# Rating the Models

Tags: r, predictive-modeling, time-series, ranking

I am working with Multi variate time series Analysis using different Models in R. I used `Arima`, `glm`, `H2O.gbm`, `randomforest` and `Garch` Models for the same set of data. I did predictions and calculated `RMSE` value for each Models. I have ranked these models according to `RMSE` value. But i would like to provide `ratings` like movie ratings to these models based on their RMSE and rank value.

```
> df <- transform(df,rank = ave(RMSE, 
           FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "first")))
> df
         Model      RMSE  MAPE rank
1        arima  410770.6 0.510    1
2          glm  571215.2 0.841    3
3      H2O.gbm  501895.3 0.449    2
4 randomforest 1157233.0 1.746    4
5        Garch 1161791.0 1.840    5
```

Any suggestions on how to provide rating to these Models? for example, i would like to score all the models out of 10. Any method or process to provide ratings to these Models? Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.
Magg

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to map your models on a scale of 1-10? If you are thinking of error linearly, then we can just find a linear transformation with your MAPE (or RMSE) scores. We "map" 0.449 to 10 and 1.840 to 1. So basically mapping "MAPE" to "Rating" by

Rating = 12.9051 - 6.47017*MAPE

You can do a similar thing with RMSE. I'm not sure how meaningful this will be though.